# What GSM middleware will "Ubuntu for phones" use?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

There are bunch of existing free software solutions for handling GSM modem in phone solutions, for instance Qtopia (maintained now by community as QtMoko), freesmartphone.org and oFono. I couldn't find any information about what Ubuntu will use on mobile phones or if it will come with something brand new.

Was this decision already made? If yes, then which technology has been chosen?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it will be running on top of the Android kernel, and the same radio drivers which are currently used on Android, will be used on Ubuntu for phones.

Comment: No, radio drivers is one thing and software which actually talks to the modem is another. I'm asking about the second one.

Comment: Do you mean the "phone" application? The drivers are what talks to the hardware.

Comment: Kernel drivers provide interface to talk with the modem, but between kernel and UI apps there has to be some interface (for instance dbus based) which maintains connection, provides way to initiate calls, notifies about new messages etc.

It's easy to imagine with AT-based modems: kernel provides device in /dev directory to which you can talk, but it would be insane to expect UI apps to talk to modem directly using AT commands.

That's what FSO and oFono does, abstracting different modem interfaces into DBus framework. Qtopia has its own, integrated solution.

Comment: Seems like it's using oFono via Telepathy bridge :(